# Classifying index 2 subgroups of $\langle a, b, c \mid ab = ba, c^2 = 1 \rangle$ up to isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory, free-product

Let $G := \langle a, b, c \mid ab = ba, c^2 = 1 \rangle$. By considering non-trivial homomorphisms $\phi : G \rightarrow \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, there are exactly 7 subgroups of $G$ given by kernels of $\phi$.

Let $H_{(n, m, k)}$ be the kernel of $\phi: G \rightarrow \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ with $\phi(a) = n$, $\phi(b) = m$, and $\phi(c) = k$.

Clearly, $H_{(0, 1, 0)} \cong H_{(1, 0, 0)}$ and $H_{(0, 1, 1)} \cong H_{(1, 0, 1)}$. Moreover, $H_{(n, m, 0)} \not\cong H_{(n', m', 1)}$ as $H_{(n, m, 0)}$ has an order 2 element, but $H_{(n', m', 1)}$ doesn't.

Now, I am not sure how to complete the classification. In particular, I need to prove whether the following pairs are isomorphic/non-isomorphic to each others:
$(H_{(0, 1, 0)}, H_{(1, 1, 0)})$, $(H_{(0, 1, 1)}, H_{(1, 1, 1)})$, $(H_{(0, 1, 1)}, H_{(0, 0, 1)})$, and $(H_{(0, 0, 1)}, H_{(1, 1, 1)})$.

I would appreciate any hint or reference.

Comment: This is a presentation for $$(\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z)\ast\Bbb Z_2,$$ where $\ast$ is the free product.

Comment: $H_{(0,0,1)} = \langle a, b \rangle$ is commutative whereas I think the others aren't.

Comment: You could use GAP for this.

Comment: Hopefully I am not missing something obvious, but isn't $H_{(0, 1, 0)} = \langle a,b^2,c : ab^2 = b^2a, c^2 = 1 \rangle$ and  $H_{(1, 1, 0)} = \langle a^2,b^2,c : a^2b^2 = b^2a^2, c^2 = 1 \rangle$? So the map $a \mapsto a^2$ and identity on $b^2, c$ gives the isomorphism? With suitable modifications showing that all other pairs are isomorphic too?

Comment: @Dylan $H_{(1,1,0)}$ should also contain $ab$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Oh of course, I knew I was missing something, thanks!

Comment: Excuse my silly question, but aren't you only recovering the normal subgroups?

Comment: Just curious. Are you trying to find all two-sheeted coverings of $T^2\vee \Bbb RP^2$? (since you've included the algebraic-topology tag)

Comment: @groupoid Not all normal subgroups; normal subgroups with index 2.

Comment: @Kevin.S That's one approach I had in mind, but I am not sure finding all two-sheeted coverings is easier task. Maybe I could try to find the corresponding covering spaces for each pair, and prove either those covering spaces are isomorphic or not.